# Wordpress page thumbnail not showing

Tags: wordpress, thumbnails

I use the following code to show the featured image of an wordpress page as thumbnail when I view the full page `single.php`

```
<div class="entry">
    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { the_post_thumbnail(); }             
     the_content(); ?>
</div>
```

Is there something wrong with my code, because the thumbnail is not showing and the page in question has a featured image set ?
Any ideas will be appreciated !

Comment: is it in the [loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop)?

Comment: Yes. in the while loop.

Comment: The problem was that I write the code inside single.php but there was also a page.php. After adding the code to page.php everything went perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I write the code inside single.php but there was also a page.php. After adding the code to page.php everything went perfect.